# RMI exception: java.lang.InvalidClassException

Tags: java, rmi

```
public class AddClient implements Serializable {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            String addServerURL = "rmi://" + "127.0.0.1" + "/AddServer";
            AddServerIntf addServerIntf = (AddServerIntf) Naming.lookup(addServerURL);
            System.out.println("msg from inside"+addServerIntf.register(new AddClient()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

I have this class and its working its task properly, but when I want this add a method to it like

```
public void retrive(String msg) {
    System.out.println(msg);
}
```

It generates Exception:

```
java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
java.io.InvalidClassException: rmi.AddClient; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 7584986215301760999, local class serialVersionUID = 9065682220695232722
```

But I didn't even use call the method from anywhere but there comes the exception. I have never encountered this kind of problem so can any one tell me what I should do.

Comment: You need the common JAR on both client and server.  Sounds like you failed to update the server JAR.

Comment: This is ***not*** an `InvalidArgumentException`. Please be accurate.

Answer (score 3):

The exception is describing the problem:  the client is trying to unmarshal the serialized object, but it cannot because the serial version identifiers do not match.

That means that the server has serialized a different version of the AddClient class than the client is unmarshalling.

@duffymo is correct - to solve the problem both the client and server must have the same version of the AddClient class on their classpath.